# Can we create cassandra materialized view with TTL.?

Tags: cassandra

Can i create cassandra materialized view on a primary table such that materialized view will have only last 24 hours records in it.?

My reasoning for having data with TTL is, i am not interested in the data that is more than 24 hours.

Either the select query that selects all the data that is in last 24 hours for materialized view or the plain select without any condition with TTL will be good.

If my thought process is wrong, i am happy to take the feedback.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Tarun No. Even though syntax allows the TTL, this is not possible on Materialized views. So, whatever the TTL you have for the table will be used for the MV. Please take a look at jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12868